# How to modify the current td node class

Tags: jquery, datatables-1.10

How could I modify the `td` class of a current data when the data value is true?

Currently I just display an empty value, but updating the `td` class would display an icon.

```js
columnDefs: [ 
   { targets: [ 1], visible: false, searchable: false },
   { 
      targets: [ 3], 
      render: function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
         if(type === 'display') {
            if(data==true){
               // add  class 'details-secret' to current node td
               return "";
            }
         }

         return data;
      }
   },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`createdCell`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.createdCell) option as shown below:

```js
columnDefs: [
   { targets: 1, visible: false, searchable: false },
   {
      targets: 3,
      createdCell: function(cell, data, index){
         if(data == true){
            $(cell).addClass('details-secret');
         }
      }
  },
  // ... skipped ...
```

See [this example](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/advanced_init/row_callback.html) with similar method [`createdRow`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/createdRow).